# dao, tx, service structure: where to place a method querying an abstract entity?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have an abstract entity that 4 other entities inherit from. This relationship works well, however I want to query the abstract entity so that I get all entities regardless of their types. I have no idea where to place such a method since the parent entity dao is also abstract.

EntityParent (abstract) -> EntityType1, EntityType2, EntityType3, EntityType4

DAOs look like this:

EntityParentDAO (abstract) -> EntityType1DAO, EntityType2DAO, EntityType3DAO, EntityType4DAO

TX also look like this:
EntityParentTx (abstract) -> EntityType1Tx, EntityType2Tx, EntityType3Tx, EntityType4Tx

My project structure goes as follows:
Entities -> DAO for each entity -> TX for each DAO -> Service combining several TXs

There is **Service** which uses all of the **TX**s that's within the scope of my project. Is this where a criteria/HQL query should be placed? That doesn't sound quite right.

For example let's say I have a `Car` parent entity and that I have children entities `Coupe`, `Sedan`, `Minivan` and so on and I want a list of cars given a property that is common to all and therefore in the entity (and it its table) `Car`. Where would I place this query/method given the structure I'm following?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I follow the transaction inheritance, but why not make the parent dao concrete and add it there? As long as the parent is an Entity, and it has the field, you can query on it. The return type will be a list of the base type, but it will be instances of the actual type.

Ex:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
public abstract class ParentImpl implements Parent{}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("1")
public class Entity1Impl extends ParentImpl {}

public interface AbstractDao<T extends Parent> {}

public interface ConcreteParentDao<Parent> {}
```

Comment: upon taking away the Abstract part of my parent dao and my parent TX i get: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.TypeVariableImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Class` at my abstract dao (which the parent dao inherits from) and at my EntityParentDAO.

Comment: You can leave the abstract parent, and create a concrete implementation for it (abstract->parent->sub, abstract->parent->concreteparent). That way you won't break the generic inheritance. Either that or move it out of the inheritance (abstract->parent->sub to abstract->parent,abstract->sub).

Comment: I've been trying to do this, I assume without any Table/Entity annotations because they give me redundancy errors in my application. Is this correct? Should the concrete parent have them or perhaps inheritance type annotations? Using this method I've been having other problems though I'm not sure if they are related (such as NPEs when fetching etc).

Comment: Err... actually I've been getting NPEs on my dao test on this abstract entity so I'm pretty sure it is related.

Comment: The generic for the DAO should be the parent type. The parent entity should have Table/Entity annotations. It should also have Inheritance and possibly DescriminatorColumn depending on your inheritance strategy.

Comment: The solution was simpler than that, I removed the abstract from my parent class and then made new DAOs with the parent generic instead of the inheritance-type generic. I marked it as answered either way. Thank you because otherwise I would have kept overlooking my ignorance at DAO inheritance.